# Devise + Administrate: ActionController::RoutingError - uninitialized constant Admin::SessionsController:

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, administrate

I created a rails (6.0.3) app and I added the [thoughtbot/administrate](https://github.com/thoughtbot/administrate/) and [devise](https://github.com/heartcombo/devise).
I have a `User` model for normal users and another `AdminUser`. I want to keep separated both types of users. Both were created with the devise generator

```sh
$ rails generate devise User
$ rails generate devise AdminUser
```

I'm having trouble with the route configuration of administrate and devise scope.

```rb
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users
  devise_scope :user do
    get 'log-in', to: 'devise/sessions#new'
    get 'sign-up', to: 'devise/registrations#new'
    delete 'log-out', to: 'devise/sessions#destroy'
    get 'reset-password', to: 'devise/passwords#new'
  end

  root 'pages#index'

  get '/dashboard', to: 'pages#dashboard'

  namespace :admin do
    devise_for :admin_users

    resources :users
    resources :groups

    root to: 'users#index'
  end
end
```

I guess I'm missing something because it throwing an exception when I go to `localhost:3000/admin` and it redirects to `http://localhost:3000/admin/admin_users/sign_in`.
Here the exception:

```sh
Started GET "/admin" for ::1 at 2021-02-13 11:58:13 -0300
Processing by Admin::UsersController#index as HTML
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 2ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms | Allocations: 207)


Started GET "/admin/admin_users/sign_in" for ::1 at 2021-02-13 11:58:13 -0300

ActionController::RoutingError - uninitialized constant Admin::SessionsController:

Started POST "/__better_errors/6ee21cb1da542538/variables" for ::1 at 2021-02-13 11:58:13 -0300
```

the administrate application controller looks like this:

```rb
module Admin
  class ApplicationController < Administrate::ApplicationController
    before_action :authenticate_admin_user!

    protected

    def authenticate_admin_user!
      authenticate_admin_admin_user!
    end
  end
end
```

LMK if there is something useful that I missed.
Thanks in advance

Comment: The error is telling you that you have not define your  'admin/sessions_controller.rb' file as you are using `devise_for :admin_users` for this, and you are using session different for normal user so you have to define admin users controller too.

Comment: ohh! I just defined the sessions controller extended from devise session controller and it works! `SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController`. Awesome! thanks @KamalPanhwar!

Comment: Please accept answer, and vote would be appreciate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is telling you that you have to define your controller.

```
admin/session_controller.rb
```

So create a controller which extended from devise session as you are using session different for normal user so you have to define admin users controller too.